# Adding image to word document using OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

I developed an app that is supposed to add an image to a word document. It takes a copy from the word document and adds the picture to the copy. I tried to add text and it worked just fine but by adding images the word document wants to open a file, by giving an error (the file "name" cannot be opened because there are problems with the content.)

My code looks like this :

```
File.Copy(file, newFile, true);
     WordprocessingDocument wordFile = WordprocessingDocument.Open(newFile, true);
     Body body = wordFile.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

     var picture = new Picture();
     var shape = new Shape() { Style = "width: 20px; height: 20px" };
     var imageData = new ImageData() { RelationshipId = "img" };

     shape.Append(imageData);
     picture.Append(shape);
     wordFile.MainDocumentPart.AddExternalRelationship(
          "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image",
           new Uri(link_of_image, UriKind.Absolute),"img");

     Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
     Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
     run.AppendChild(new Picture(picture));

     wordFile.Close();
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: What is "link_of_image" here? Is it supposed to be a valid file path? And does the image exist?

Comment: @KerriBrown the image doesn't exist on the computer its a link to an image uploaded to a server as an example ("something.com/Images/image.png")

Comment: There are other things you can do to investigate. For example, try an image stored on your local machine, remove the "wordFile.MainDocumentPart.AddExternalRelationship" and see if you still get the error etc.

Answer (score 6):

This solution for adding an image on your local drive, but i don't know how to add it from an online server
solution: 
first add those assemblies:

```
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using DW = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing;
using PIC = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures;
```

Then open the file

```
        WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument =
        WordprocessingDocument.Open(newFile, true);

        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;
        ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\img.PNG", FileMode.Open))
        {
            imagePart.FeedData(stream);
        }
        AddImageToBody(wordprocessingDocument, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));

        wordprocessingDocument.Close();
```

Then define the reference of the image and append the reference to the body.

```
var element =
     new Drawing(
         new DW.Inline(
             new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
             new DW.EffectExtent()
             {
                 LeftEdge = 0L,
                 TopEdge = 0L,
                 RightEdge = 0L,
                 BottomEdge = 0L
             },
             new DW.DocProperties()
             {
                 Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                 Name = "Picture 1"
             },
             new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                 new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
             new A.Graphic(
                 new A.GraphicData(
                     new PIC.Picture(
                         new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                             new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                             {
                                 Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                 Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                             },
                             new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                         new PIC.BlipFill(
                             new A.Blip(
                                 new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                     new A.BlipExtension()
                                     {
                                         Uri =
                                           "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                     })
                             )
                             {
                                 Embed = relationshipId,
                                 CompressionState =
                                 A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                             },
                             new A.Stretch(
                                 new A.FillRectangle())),
                         new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                             new A.Transform2D(
                                 new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                 new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                             new A.PresetGeometry(
                                 new A.AdjustValueList()
                             ) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                 ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
         )
         {
             DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
             DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
             DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
             DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
             EditId = "50D07946"
         });

wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));
```

Reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430.aspx

Comment: Or you can add the drawing directly to any position in the document.

Pass the paragraph or item to the method

paragraph.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));