# Adding image in word document

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, openxml, docx

When I add an image to a word document then, when I open word it is showing me an XML error. The file cannot be opened because there is a problem with the content.

See error -> [image: Word Error]

I took reference from the below link.

> [Adding image to word document using OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453817/adding-image-to-word-document-using-openxml)

and from Microsoft site

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-a-word-processing-document

**My Code is as follows**: add Open XML to your project reference.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System.IO;
using DW = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using PIC = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures;

namespace InsertImageWord
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //References
            //https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Doc/OpenXML/How-to-Insert-a-picture-into-a-word-processing-document.html
            //https://coders-corner.net/2015/04/11/open-xml-add-a-picture/
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-insert-a-picture-into-a-word-processing-document
            //file name
            string folder = @"E:\TestImage";
            string fileName = folder + @"\BlankDocument.doc";
            string imageFileName = folder + @"\DesertTest.png";

            //create file
            using (var file = WordprocessingDocument.Create(
                fileName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                file.AddMainDocumentPart();

                //add image part and add image from file
                ImagePart imagePart = file.MainDocumentPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);

                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(imageFileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    imagePart.FeedData(stream);
                }

                //set content
                var text = new Text("Hello Open XML world");
                var run = new Run(text);
                var paragraph = new Paragraph(run);
                var body = new Body(paragraph);
                var document = new Document(body);

                //add image
                Drawing imageElement = GetImageElement(
                    file.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart),
                    imageFileName,
                    "my image",
                    22,
                    22);

                body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(imageElement)));

                //save
                file.MainDocumentPart.Document = document;
                file.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
            }
        }

        private static Drawing GetImageElement(
            string imagePartId,
            string fileName,
            string pictureName,
            double width,
            double height)
        {
            double englishMetricUnitsPerInch = 914400;
            double pixelsPerInch = 96;

            //calculate size in emu
            double emuWidth = width * englishMetricUnitsPerInch / pixelsPerInch;
            double emuHeight = height * englishMetricUnitsPerInch / pixelsPerInch;

            var element = new Drawing(
                new DW.Inline(
                    new DW.Extent { Cx = (Int64Value)emuWidth, Cy = (Int64Value)emuHeight },
                    new DW.EffectExtent { LeftEdge = 0L, TopEdge = 0L, RightEdge = 0L, BottomEdge = 0L },
                    new DW.DocProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = pictureName },
                    new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                    new A.GraphicFrameLocks { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                    new A.Graphic(
                        new A.GraphicData(
                            new PIC.Picture(
                                new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                    new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = (UInt32Value)0U, Name = fileName },
                                    new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                new PIC.BlipFill(
                                    new A.Blip(
                                        new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                            new A.BlipExtension { Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}" }))
                                    {
                                        Embed = imagePartId,
                                        CompressionState = A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                    },
                                            new A.Stretch(new A.FillRectangle())),
                                new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                    new A.Transform2D(
                                        new A.Offset { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                        new A.Extents { Cx = (Int64Value)emuWidth, Cy = (Int64Value)emuHeight }),
                                    new A.PresetGeometry(
                                        new A.AdjustValueList())
                                    { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle })))
                        {
                            Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"
                        }))
                {
                    DistanceFromTop = 0U,
                    DistanceFromBottom = 0U,
                    DistanceFromLeft = 0U,
                    DistanceFromRight = 0U,
                    EditId = "50D07946"
                });
            return element;
        }

    }
}
```

**Please help me out of this. Thanks in Advance**

Comment: If using openXML is not important to you. I will recommend using xceed instead of openXML, that will be easier.

This link can be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658848/c-sharp-net-docx-add-an-image-to-a-docx-file,

Also, check your image size, sometimes too large images can cause an error like this.

Comment: okay, thanks but do u have an idea about the error for Open XML?

Comment: I had a similar error when tried to add 15 Mb image. How large is your image?

Comment: 23.3 KB is the image Size @RubenMartirosyan can u share your code if it is working?

Comment: At the moment I don't have access to that, maybe you could share your code and we will try to see if there is an error?

Comment: @RubenMartirosyan Thanks for this help I have updated the code. You can check in console application adding Open XML package to your project.

Comment: your image is jpg, apparently AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png) doesnt like that

Comment: @Bacon Thanks I have changed now but still, error while opening the word document. Can you try in your machine?

Comment: your code worked for me, did you rename your jpg to png or convert?

Comment: Hi @Bacon I have changed it but same error. Can you send the code on thakor_tejas@yahoo.com ? Many thanks. I will verify and accept your answer.

Comment: I am also facing a similar problem, can you let me know what the fix was. I have verified the ImageType is the same. Still getting the same error/ Badly need a answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your imageparttype has to match the mimetype of your image
[image]
[image]